# Expected OFFICIAL GUI Release Date?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

So what is the general consensus for the expected release date for the OFFICIAL GUI?... Are we looking at this week? Next week?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the following link the beta is just around the corner as this was posted 1 month ago.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/50ixic/first_gui_beta_coming_by_mbg033_%E8%B7%AF_pull_request_6/

Slightly off topic, but still surprisingly on topic,
Exodus and Jaxx are amazing professional GUI wallets that include Monero, and for most people it will be enough, and potentially even better than the official GUI for simple functions like storing and sending XMR. Perhaps one unified interface that connects many coins is better than one for each coin although having an official GUI would go a long way to making a coin look more mature and complete. Even so, I foresee most people using a multi-coin wallet in the future.